# Find out when the last failover occurred in AlwaysOn availability groups

Tags: sql-server, alwayson, automatic-failover

I used below metioned query to find out if any failover happened in the last 30 minutes

```
create table #errormsg(duration datetime,errornum int,dbmessage varchar(max))
DECLARE @tags3 VARCHAR(5000)SET @tags3  = (SELECT CAST( t.target_data AS XML ).value('(EventFileTarget/File/@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions s INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets t ON s.address = t.event_session_address WHERE t.target_name = 'event_file' and s.name='AlwaysOn_health'); 
IF @tags3 is Not NULL begin WITH cte_HADR AS (SELECT object_name, CONVERT(XML, event_data) AS data FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(@tags3, null, null, null)WHERE object_name = 'error_reported')
insert into #errormsg SELECT  data.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime')AS [timestamp],data.value('(/event/data[@name=''error_number''])[1]','int') AS [error_number],data.value('(/event/data[@name=''message''])[1]','varchar(max)') AS [message] FROM cte_HADR WHERE data.value('(/event/data[@name=''error_number''])[1]','int') = 1480 select  distinct GETDATE() as currenttime, er.duration,dbs.name  from #errormsg er  inner join sys.databases dbs on er.dbmessage LIKE '%"' +dbs.name+'"%'  where er.duration>=(DATEADD(mi,-30,GETDATE()) );
drop table #errormsg;end 
else IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDB.dbo.#errormsg', N'U') IS NOT NULL drop table #errormsg;
```

But I did not get the result I was expecting because of the "Incorrect Timestamp on Events in Extended Events".

1. In SSMS -->Management-->Extended Events-->Sessions-->AlwaysOn_health--> click event file.

   In that event file,

   ```
    I checked recently role changed time for 'availablity_replica_state_change'.
   ```
2. In MSSQL log folder--> availablity_replica_state_change time in "AlwaysOn_health" file

timestamp in (1) and (2) needs to be same.

But for me its shows different time. So I didn't get the proper result.

Instead of using extended events, Is there any query to read the MS SQL error logs?

Is there any query to find out if any failover happened in the last 30 minutes?

Please help me to find a solution for this .